# Sorting Comma Separated Values in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I have a column/field in Redshift with comma separated values.

| my_field |
| --- |
| apple,banana,candy |
| candy,banana |
| banana,apple |

And I want to turn these into

| my_field_sorted |
| --- |
| apple,banana,candy |
| banana,candy |
| apple,banana |

Is there an easy way to do this with native SQL/Redshift syntax?
Do I have to resort to UDFs?

I don't have any experience creating UDFs - does anyone have a similar UDFs that they can share?

Or can someone help turn this function into an UDF?

```
def sort_comma_sep_values(x):
  if type(x) is str:
    list_of_x = x.split(',')
    list_of_x = list(dict.fromkeys(list_of_x))
    list_of_x = sorted(list_of_x)
    output = ','.join(list_of_x)
    return output
  else:
    return None
```

Comment: *Why* do you have a field with comma separated values in a relational database system? Fix your database schema, make a related table with a foreign key, and not only will your your sorting go a way, it will also be considerably faster.

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for the feedback, I must add, this is a legacy decision/design that was passed down to me that I think would be hard for me to change :-(

Comment: Hm. You could add a secondary table which contains the individual values as rows + foreign key, and provides a basis for your queries. A trigger can then split inserted values at the source table, and transfer them to the secondary table. This way you could leave the "application-facing" side of your database unchanged. Inserting a CSV value into your primary table, and everything that depends on those values would continue to work just as before. At the same time you could enjoy the advantages of a proper relational setup without breaking anything.

Comment: @Tomalak ooh that might work! Imma give it a try!

Comment: Don't forget the "on update" and "on delete" triggers (or an "on delete cascade" foreign key) but if I was allowed to modify the database schema, that's what I would do.

Comment: Also look at [LISTAGG()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html) to turn rows into a separated list again, if you need. Denormalizing data is always easier than the other way around.